# How to modify a specific variables in another file and use it in other different file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three files and I need to use one variable in these three files but the problem is when I use the variable in the third file `test.py`, it uses the first value from `var.py`. Also, when I define a new variable in the `run.py` and import the variable in the third file `test.py`, it keeps running without run the third file `test.py` and give this message `non-resource variables are not supported in the long term`. In addition, I still have a file `env.py` that I import in 'test.py' using the modified 'var.demend'

**var.py**

```
demend=-1
```

**run.py**

```
import  var
print(var.demend)
for i in range(0,6)  :
    var.demend=i

    gc.collect()
    bots = [subprocess.check_call(["python"+version, os.path.join(current_dir, "test.py")])])]
    modules = map(__import__,bots)
    import multiprocessing,subprocess
    for bot in (bots):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda: __import__(bot))
        p.start()
```

**test.py**

```
import  env
import  var
print(var.demend)
```

**env.py**

```
import  var
print(var.demend)
```

Comment: I need to pass different values from 0 to 6 and use the `var.demend` in the `run.py`

Comment: @kabanus I will try to use it

Comment: don't read it from file but send this value as argument when you run subprocess and get it in code as `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: @kabanus  thanks for your suggestion, it works, I was using the `sys.argv[1]` in different file.

Comment: @furas thank you for your reply, I use `sys.argv[1]` in the `test.py` and `env.py` and `bots = [subprocess.check_call(["python"+version, os.path.join(current_dir, "test.py"),str(i)])])]`. It works after reading the @kabanus  answer and suggestion but he removes his answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use the  `demend` in **run.py** file  and then I pass the new parameter  `str(i)`

**run.py**

```
import os
import  var
import subprocess,_multiprocessing
import sys
import gc # Garbage Collector
print(var.demend)
version = ".".join(map(str, sys.version_info[:3]))
if len(version) >3:
    version=version[:-2];
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
for i in range(0,6)  :
    demend=i

    gc.collect()
    bots = [subprocess.check_call(["python"+version, os.path.join(current_dir, "test.py"),str(i)])]
    modules = map(__import__,bots)
    import multiprocessing,subprocess
    for bot in (bots):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=lambda: __import__(bot))
        p.start()
```

In the **test.py** file

```
import  env
from sys import argv
demend=int(argv[1])
print(demend)
```

In the **env.py** file

```
from sys import argv
demend=int(argv[1])
print(demend)
```